# Efficiently override native appendChild for specific Elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert some special methodology for the native appendChild 
method but i would  like to override the appendChild for specific elements instead of overriding `Element.prototype.appendChild` for all elements.
i can create a method that will add my appendChild to each element but it will create unnecessary overhead for large amount of elements.
I'm currently cloning some elements from the dom (which can have many childrens) with `element.clone(true)`  and i would like to "proxy" all calls to appendChild on the cloned elements to the original ones.
can it be done more efficiently without overriding each element at a time?

Comment: Can you give an example? Which specific elements?

Comment: can you give a live example? like a fiddle or something?

Comment: There is something call `DOMMutation` but its considered very expensive. You can look for it and minimize the impact.

Comment: @CertainPerformance , Take a look at (https://jsfiddle.net/m7fx8cq9/) i would like to override the appendChild for each of the cloned node (including its childrens) but not the Element.prototype.appendChild because it will override the appendChild for everyone , i can do that for each element at a time but i think maybe there is a better way , like maybe providing a prototype when i'm cloning the nodes or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make a recursive function that creates a custom `appendChild` property on every child:

```js
function customAppendChild(elm) {
  elm.appendChild = function() {
    console.log('insert custom logic here');
  };
  [...elm.children].forEach(customAppendChild);
  return elm;
}
const clone = elm => customAppendChild(elm.cloneNode(true));

const cloned = clone(document.getElementById("test1"));
console.log(Element.prototype.appendChild);
console.log(cloned.appendChild);
console.log(cloned.children[0].appendChild)
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  <span id="test2">
  <section id="test3">
    <div id="test4">
    </div>
  </section>
</span>
</div>
```

Elements not created via `clone` won't be affected, of course. (also note that `div`s and `section`s should not be children of `span`s)

Comment: that's what i'm trying to avoid , but if it's unavoidable than this answer is probably the only method but i thought maybe there is something else like cloning the elements with custom prototype chain

Comment: If you want calls of `appendChild` on those elements to go through the custom logic without overwriting `Element.prototype.appendChild`, this sort of recursion is pretty much the only option. I think overwriting `Element.prototype.appendChild` *would* be the most performant solution by far, I can post that if you want, but mutating built-in prototypes is bad practice and results in unstable code.

Comment: overwriting the Element.prototype.appendChild is definitely out of the question , it will cause all appendChild calls on page to use my implementation , So i'm guessing looping on all of the elements is the only way.

Comment: You can set a flag on every cloned parent (no recursion) and have the new `appendChild` function check whether a parent node contains the flag. If so, use the custom logic, else use the default logic.

Comment: You're probably right but again i would prefer performance impact on overwriting appendChild for everyone , anyway i would accept your answer , thanks!